# How to select the first element of dynamically filled/unfilled Selectbox in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

```
<select ng-model="t" **ng-select="$first"**>
    <option ng-repeat="t in tees"
            value="{{ t }}">
        {{ t.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Is there something like **ng-select="$first"** ?

(P.s. don't think about t, it is OK, it is not t.value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use ng-init like this:

```
<select ng-model="t" ng-init="t=tees[0]">
    <option ng-repeat="t in tees"
            value="{{ t }}">
        {{ t.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: it was accepted as init value but it was not shown as first element, maybe I make a mistake..

Answer (score 0):

I find the below code less verbose in the view:

```
<select ng-model="t" ng-options="t.value as t.name for t in tees></select>
```

then in your controller:

```
$scope.t = $scope.tees[0].value
```

hope it helps

Comment: looks elegant, but consider: it this case you have to convert numeric data from string to integer, ng-options convert everything into strings.